# Работа с html страницой и масивами в инструмента разработки Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как в инструментах разработчика Chrome взять все теги

с некоторым классом и посортировать все  в которых находится этот тег по возрастающему порядку в зависимости от числа в теге

с этим классом. И соответсвенно это все было видно в на самой странице после этого. В пример приведен код на картинке. Тег p с числом в нем находится в div с id content0. Не обязательно скидывать полный код к даному примеру,был бы очень благодарен если сказали каким образом это делать!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function sortElements(selector, resultContainer) {
  const selectedElements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  const sortedElements = [...selectedElements].sort((a, b) => Number(a.innerHTML) > Number(b.innerHTML) ? 1 : -1);

  sortedElements.forEach(el => resultContainer.append(el));
}

const resultContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('result')[0];
sortElements(".gas", resultContainer);
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="nested">
    <div>
      <div class="nested">
        <div class="gas">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gas">25</div>
<div class="gas">7</div>
<div class="gas">2</div>
<div class="gas">8</div>

<div class="result">Results:</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,очень помогло! А еще вот такой не скромный вопрос, если div в div в котором еще один div но у всех div которые на одном уровне совпадает class можно сделать такую же сортировку используя много раз getElementsByClassName()?

Comment: Не понял вопроса) лучше новый вопрос, с кодом, потому что "дивы дивировали дивировали да не выдивировали" мне сложно представлять

Comment: Я добавил картинку с кодом и новым описанием вопроса

Comment: Если класс у целевых элементов одинаковый то никаких проблем не возникнет, какой бы уровень вложенности не был

Comment: Опять же спасибо огромнейшее, помогло разобратся с некоторыми новыми моментами! Но скорее всего я не умею ставить вопрос. Он вырезает все теги с одинаковым класом, сортирует их, и вставляет в новый div. А мне надо,чтоб оно находило тег и сортировало divы которые на 2 ступеня выше в зависимости от числа в том теге, и из даного примера получалось примерно такое

Comment: <div class="gas">2</div>
<div>
  <div class="nested">
    <div>
      <div class="nested">
        <div class="gas">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gas">7</div>
<div class="gas">8</div>
<div class="gas">25</div>

Comment: Прошу прощения, не знаю как вставлять код в коментарий. Ну так у меня вопрос, надо ли указывать дополнительные пути ? Или все таки так можно сделать указав только класс тега ?

Comment: Это возможно только при одном из условий:
1. Все родительские елементы, которые именно нужно сортировать имеют одинаковый класс, и все элементы которые содержат значение для сортировки тоже имеют одинаковый класс         2. Структура документа строгая и никогда не будет менятся, тогда можно разрулить путями относительно елемента с значением. Например, если у всех элементов со значениями родитель для сортировки строго на два уровня выше, то тогда можно.

Comment: Если хотя бі одно верно, то можно